# Related paths in c#

Tags: c#, path

I have this situation in c# application

have 2 paths in my windows

C:\Projectos\FrameworkCS\CSoft.Core
C:\Projectos2\CSoft.Core

and i need get related path of second related with first like this:

..\..\Projectos2\CSoft.Core

Exists a way to do this in c# or some one have a function can help me

Comment: Wouldn't the relative path be `..\CSoft.Core` instead of `..\..\Projectos2\CSoft.Core`?

Answer (score 5):

Try [MakeRelativeUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.makerelativeuri.aspx):

```
Uri first = new Uri(@"C:\Projectos2\CSoft.Core");
Uri second = new Uri(@"C:\Projectos\FrameworkCS\CSoft.Core ");

string relativePath = second.MakeRelativeUri(first).ToString();
```

Result:

```
"../../Projectos2/CSoft.Core"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably figure it out by splitting both using the '\' as a separator.  I would then count array items that were the same to get my common bond.  Then I would build the destination path using the remaining items in the destination array and build the ..\ string by counting the remaining items in the source.

- Common path = C:\Projectos\
- Remaining destination path = CSoft.Core
- Remaining source path has 1 more item (not including the file name itself) giving you ..\

Join the ..\ with the CSoft.Core giving you ..\CSoft.Core

**Addendum:** I didn't realise you could use the URI.MakeRelativePath() method for this - don't bother reinventing the wheel if it's already been done elsewhere.